# What is this high wing twin airplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

It sits in a very large backyard in Lancaster, California.

Comment: for people thinking it's an AeroCommander/Rockwell Commander, it's not. Vertical stab and cockpit windows (as well as the engine nacelles) are quite different.

Comment: "very large backyard" indeed!

Answer (score 15):

Occulted top cockpit windows are quite misleading in identifying this one.

It is a Percival P-50 Prince 2

[image]
([source](https://abpic.co.uk/pictures/model/Percival%20P.50%20Prince%202))

It may very well be this exact one:

[image]
([source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/46191393@N08/31809560065))

Description in source image tells: N206UP, 1953 Percival P-50 Prince 2, C/N: P50/10, Standing in a private garden near Antelope Acres CA

Also provides a googlemaps [link](http://goo.gl/maps/PCwr2QsMSC92)

Comment: The [Pembroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percival_Pembroke) was as close as I got, but the windshield made me question my find. Well done!

Comment: Yes, that is G-ALWH / N206UP now in Antelope Acres, California.  https://www.flickr.com/photos/ajw1970/27678424762

Comment: I can't be the only one who thught "occulted" meant the plane had once belonged to a diabolical sect...

Comment: @PartyArk feel free to edit, my english is poor.

Comment: No your English is perfect. It's an unusual word used entirely appropriately.